# Create array from dynamic variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am working with the following code. Every time a line is ready form the file, I need to add it to an associative array

```
$fp = fopen("printers.txt", "r"); // Open ptinters.txt to be read by fgets()


        // While not end of the file, read a line and store it in $printer
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $printer = fgets($fp, 256);


            // Split the line of text into three sections and store them into
            // variables named $pName $printerType and $numPages.
            $tempArray = explode(":", $printer); 

            $pName = $tempArray[0];
            $printerType = $tempArray[1];
            $numPages = $tempArray[2];


            //Create 2 arrays. First stores $pName and $printerType 
            // second stores $pName and $numPages 


        }; // Close while !feof $fp loop.

fclose($fp); // close $fp file pointer stream.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates array1 = `[name] => printertype` and array2 = `[name] => numpages`.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
$fp = fopen("printers.txt", "r"); // Open ptinters.txt to be read by fgets()
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $printer = fgets($fp, 256);
    $tempArray = explode(":", $printer); 
    $array1[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[1];
    $array2[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[2];
}
fclose($fp);
```

if you have duplicate printer names do the following which gives you array1 `array{[0] => array([name] => printertype),...[n] => array([name] => printertype)}` and array2 `array{[0] => array([name] => numpages),...[n] => array([name] => numpages)}`

```
$i = 0;
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $printer = fgets($fp, 256);
    $tempArray = explode(":", $printer); 
    $array1[$i] = array($tempArray[0] => $tempArray[1]);
    $array2[$i] = array($tempArray[0] => $tempArray[2]);
    $i++;
}
```

based on your comments:

```
$pType = array();
$pages = array();
$fp = fopen("printers.txt", "r"); // Open ptinters.txt to be read by fgets()
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $printer = fgets($fp, 256);
    $tempArray = explode(":", $printer);

    $pName = $tempArray[0];
    $printerType = $tempArray[1];
    $numPages = $tempArray[2];

    $pType[$pName] = $printerType;
    $pages[$pName] = $numPages;
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: A sentence or two explaining the problem/solution would probably help the OP

Comment: I understand how you are doing the array creation in the bottom half but is there a way to do it with the variable names? The spec says i have to use the $pName, $printerType, and $numPages to populate the arrays.

Comment: you can see in the first example `$array1[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[1];` which uses `$tempArray[0]` as the assoc array name, which is the same thing as `$pName` just set to a different var name

Comment: I am still unsure of how to do it that way. My specs may help us both be on the same page.
~
Open the file printers.txt and store a filepointer to it in $fp
~
Use fgets() inside a while loop to read in data from the file, one line at a time. Store each line in a variable named $printer until you reach end of file.
~
Break up each line of data into fields storing the valiables in variables named $pName, $printerType, and $numPages
~
As soon as you read a line store the printer name and type into array $pType
~
As soon as you read a line store the printer name and page count into array $pages

Comment: so just change `$array1` to `$pType` and `$array2` to `$pages`

Comment: When i run your code i get the error i was having when i ran mine 

"Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: can you post a sample of what the `printers.txt` has at least a few lines will be sufficient.

Comment: bec155:Lexmark 4557XL:45800 ~ end of line ~
bec152:HP LaserJet 8MQ:28009 ~ end of line ~
bec159:Canon CopyExpress 900:425000 ~ end of line ~
I also am just trying to "print $pType;" to verify array contents... is that the wrong way to show that in php?

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/hFSqyr) not using a txt file but its nearly the same. I think you are echoing a array directly which you should do a `var_dump($pType);` which is why you are getting that notice;

Comment: I tried using a foreach loop and echo with var names and it worked correctly. I simply had the wrong output chosen. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: feel free to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$types = $nums = array();

$fp = fopen('printers.txt', 'r');

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $printer = fgets($fp, 256);

    list($name, $type, $pages) = explode(':', $printer); 

    $types[] = compact('name', 'type');
    $nums[]  = compact('name', 'pages');
}

fclose($fp);

print_r($types);
print_r($nums);
```